# Cannot change the text of TextView on Button Press

Tags: android, textview, android-button

What I want is every time a user goes from one text in the textview (q) the textview (nm) shows  the number at which the user is. In Brief, every time the value of variable changes, i want to set that value to the text at TexView (nm) . But, Here It shows an error.

## The Button doesn't work. What's wrong?

### LOGCAT

```
04-01 19:54:55.901: E/AndroidRuntime(32078): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-01 19:54:55.901: E/AndroidRuntime(32078): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-01 19:54:55.901: E/AndroidRuntime(32078):    at com.dreamgoogle.gihf.Quotes$1.onClick(Quotes.java:43)
04-01 19:54:55.901: E/AndroidRuntime(32078):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3524)
04-01 19:54:55.901: E/AndroidRuntime(32078):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14194)
04-01 19:54:55.901: E/AndroidRuntime(32078):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
04-01 19:54:55.901: E/AndroidRuntime(32078):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-01 19:54:55.901: E/AndroidRuntime(32078):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-01 19:54:55.901: E/AndroidRuntime(32078):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4476)
04-01 19:54:55.901: E/AndroidRuntime(32078):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-01 19:54:55.901: E/AndroidRuntime(32078):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-01 19:54:55.901: E/AndroidRuntime(32078):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:816)
04-01 19:54:55.901: E/AndroidRuntime(32078):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:583)
04-01 19:54:55.901: E/AndroidRuntime(32078):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: please show us the error...

Comment: @Abhi yes please post your logcat.

Comment: I can't as yet post images. How should I show Logcat?

Comment: @Abhi copy and paste it click on the first line of your error and hold shift and click on the last line of your error. Then `Ctrl` + `c` and post it here.

Comment: You do have all the Button next = (Button) findViewById(R....) code in there, right?

Comment: @Abhi can you post how you define your buttons, textviews, etc. Also what is line 43? Use [this](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090225074741AAuJwOK) to figure out which line that is.

Comment: yes please post line Quotes.java:43

Comment: nm.setText(String.valueOf(i)) ;

Comment: and where did you call findViewById???

Comment: @Abhi. What Bill Mote said is what I think your problem is. You need to use `findViewById` for all of your layout items.

Comment: I have that in the method varSet().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is `nm` is never bound to a component in the view.
Thats the reason for the NPE here:

```
nm.setText(String.valueOf(i)) ;
```

Add this to your class:

```
private void varSet() {
        next = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.next);
        previous = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.previous);
        copytext = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.copy);
        q = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quotes);
        nm = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.YOUR_ID); // BOUND nm HERE WITH YOUR ID
        str = new String[] {
                "In order to succeed, your desire for success should be greater than your fear of failure.",
                "A successful man is one who can lay a firm foundation with the bricks others have thrown at him.",
                "Success is not final, failure is not fatal: it is the courage to continue that counts.",
                "Try not to become a man of success. Rather become a man of value.",
                 };

    };
```

Comment: Problem Solved! :D|
I'm new to android, developing my first application , after all that reading and "example" stuff. And hence this poor initialization error problem. Thanks a Lot.

Answer (score 0):

"i" is an integer.  Use String.valueOf(i), StringBuilder or substitution String.format("%d", i));

Comment: It still doesn't work. The app crashes as soon as I press the Button.

Answer (score 0):

If your views are initialized properly, most probable thing is that your string array is null. Change this:

```
String[] str;
```

with this

```
String[] str = new String[]{"Hahahaha", "Woohoo!", "It's-a-me, Mario!", "Mamma mia!"};
```

Comment: I already have string arrays downthere. If I remove the " nm " set text method, the application just works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you had declared the variable .But you forget to initialize them

```
ImageButton next;
ImageButton previous;
ImageButton copytext;
TextView q;
TextView nm;
```

For these widegets you must intalize them

eg :`previous=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.name_in_your_layout_xml);`

or if it is dynamic

`previous= new ImageButton(context);`

I think you Forget to do this.Thats why its showing the NPE

Edit :If you use any function to set this the call it `onCreare()` 
In your case you must call it before click events

EDIT with your new code
you forget to give this

```
nm = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_id_layout_xml);
```

Comment: No  nO. Check out the whole class file . I did that in the method varSet().

Comment: Where are you setting values for i?? you had only declared i but didn't initalize that

Comment: In the button's onClickListener method. Anyways, Problem Solved.